# How would I create an encrypted PDF in PHP that can be decrypted after download within PDF Reader?

Tags: php, pdf, encryption, pdf-generation

I want to encrypt a PDF file with PHP (I have found some solutions online for this), but I want to make it so the decryption can be done directly in the PDF Reader application on the user's desktop (and not from PHP)?

Is this possible?

Scenario:

1. User fills out form and submits
2. Server creates encrypted PDF and emails it to someone
3. Receiving person gets new email and opens encrypted PDF attachment
4. PDF opens in their PDF Reader and requests a private key (preferably) or password to decrypt

Answer (score 4):

Do this: (taken from: [How to create a passsword protected pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545804/how-to-create-a-passsword-protected-pdf-file))

http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/fpdi.zip

```
<?php
    function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile){
        require_once('FPDI_Protection.php');
        $pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
        $pdf->FPDF('P', 'in');
        //Calculate the number of pages from the original document.
        $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);
        //Copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one.
        for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
            $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
            $pdf->addPage();
            $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
        }

        //Protect the new pdf file, and allow no printing, copy, etc. and
        //leave only reading allowed.
        $pdf->SetProtection(array(), $password);
        $pdf->Output($destFile, 'F');
        return $destFile;
    }

    //Password for the PDF file (I suggest using the email adress of the purchaser).
    $password = "testpassword";
    //Name of the original file (unprotected).
    $origFile = "sample.pdf";
    //Name of the destination file (password protected and printing rights removed).
    $destFile ="sample_protected.pdf";
    //Encrypt the book and create the protected file.
    pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );
?>
```

Comment: Three questions: 1. What type of encryption is that using? Can I specify the algorithms to use? (e.g. ElGamal) 2. Will this open as a locked PDF but just ask for password? 3. Is it possible to have it ask for private key instead of password?

Comment: 1). RC4 - I don't see any options, but if you're savy, I'm sure you could. 2). Yes - asks for a password. 3). I'm not sure if PDF readers support that - but, if they do, then you most certainly could, simply by replacing the value of `$password` with the value of your private key.

Comment: Thanks. If I could at least use AES-128, I'd prefer that over RC4. I suppose the value of the private key could act as a long password, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Well, maybe this will put your mind at ease : howsecureismypassword.net

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good idea because in that way you should:

1. Store a key or password inside the generated PDF file
   that is obviously not reliable;
2. OR: Send the typed key to some server but PDF format 
   doesn't allow that;
3. OR: Implement your own PDF Reader with support of some 
   custom non-standart extensions that is also not a best 
   decition.

I think it's better to do some web-based document viewer with [encryption and keys](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/im-going-to-build-my-own-theme-park-with-blackjack-and-hookers) or something else.

UPD: proprietary [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdf-security/encryption/) allows a compatible encryption

UPD2: open-source [iSafePDF](http://isafepdf.eurekaa.org/) allows it too

Comment: #1 makes no sense. I'd encrypt it with a public key and the decryption would use a private key, neither of which would need to be in the pdf.

Comment: @DonRhummy lol, yes, didn't think about private key, and yes pdf encryption is allowed by at least proprietary readers, sorry :-)

Comment: @DonRhummy try [this](http://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdf-security/encryption/) — may be it's ok

Comment: That's closed source and costs thousands of dollars.

Comment: @DonRhummy what about [iSafePDF](http://isafepdf.eurekaa.org/)?

Comment: @DonRhummy you can write a PHP binding or you can port it to PHP :-)